# Tangent bundle of $S^2 \times S^1$ trivial or not

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Is the tangent bundle of $S^2 \times S^1$ trivial or not?

Comment: It is trivial: it is isomorphic to $pr_1^*T_{S^2}\oplus pr_2^*T_{S^1}$, that is, to the pull back of $T_{S^2}\oplus \varepsilon $, which is trivial.

Comment: @abx: Bravo!   I suppose the ambiguity of  the word"trivial" in your statement was deliberate,  although I find  it ingenious to show how trivial the proof of triviality of the vector bundle can be made :-)

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: Actually I missed the pun, I used "trivial" in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is trivial.

More generally, by a result of Kervaire a product of any number $n \geq 2$   of spheres is a parallelizable manifold if one of them has odd dimension.

For a short proof see

*E. B. Staples*, [**A short and elementary proof that a product of spheres is parallelizable if one of them is odd**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=219082), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **18** (1967), 570--571.

Comment: Actually every orientable $3$-manifold is parallelizable.

Comment: Right, $S^2 \times S^1$ is parallelizable for several reasons. So there are several possible generalizations.